# Determine active distribution via shell script

Tags: texlive, mactex, scripts, bash, macos

### Background:

Currently, I have installed

```
/usr/local/texlive/2016
/usr/local/texlive/2017
/usr/local/texlive/2018
```

With TeXLive, I can use the `TeX Live Utility.app` to select which TeX distribution to use

[image]

### Questions:

1. How can I obtain the value of this setting in a bash variable?
2. Is is possible to set this value via the command line?

### Platform

- MacOS High Sierra (Version 10.13.4)

Comment: `kpsewhich -var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT` returns `/usr/local/texlive/2018` (or whatever year the installed distribution refers to).

Comment: Well that was easy. Woks great.

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman although better to set PATH than  set SELFAUTOPARENT

Comment: You shouldn't mess with the system $PATH variable though. Seems like `kpsewhich` uses the system one.

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman If I run `env SELFAUTOPARENT='/usr/local/texlive/2017' kpsewhich -var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT`, the terminal returns `/usr/local/texlive/2018`. Differently from other `kpse` variables, the `SELF...` ones are not looked at when program linked to `libkpse` are launched.

Comment: Yeah. Doesn't work. Good catch. I tested with 2018, which was mind-boggingly stupid because I am already using 2018, heh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TeX Live relies on the `kpse` library and MacTeX is based on TeX Live.

Basically, all TeX related programs are linked to the library, whose primary job is to set up several environment variables starting from the location the program sits in.

So, for example, if you run `pdflatex` and the binary resides in `/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-darwin/` (usually the location is determined via a soft link), the main variables that are set are (from `texmf.cnf`

```
% SELFAUTOLOC (directory of the binary=/usr/local/texlive/YYYY/bin/i386-linux),
% SELFAUTODIR (its parent = /usr/local/texlive/YYYY/bin), 
% SELFAUTOPARENT (its grandparent = /usr/local/texlive/YYYY), and
% SELFAUTOGRANDPARENT (its great-grandparent = /usr/local/texlive).
```

These four variables are set based on the location of the binary and used for locating the relevant `texmf.cnf` files (see the documentation of the library, `texdoc kpathsea`) which will set all the other necessary variables.

A program for querying the setup is `kpsewhich`; among other options, it can report the value of environment variables, including those that are set at program launch by `kpse`; so

```
kpsewhich -var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT
```

will return, on my machine,

```
/usr/local/texlive/2018
```

from which you can easily extract the year, if needed.

Just for information, when I want to test a document with different versions of TeX Live, instead of changing the distribution via the panel I just directly call the binary:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-darwin pdflatex
```

because the `SELFAUTOLOC` feature will set the environment to what results from reading the `texmf.cnf` files from the 2017 distribution.

Comment: This answer is correct as far as it goes, but the OP will end up with different TeX distributions being used on the command line vs. GUI programs (such as TeX Live Utility, BibDesk, or TeXShop) if they are configured to use `/Library/TeX/texbin`.

Comment: @AdamMaxwell That’s a series of links pointing to the same place, the directory containing the binaries for the currently chosen TeX Live distribution.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's a series of links. This may meet the OP's needs by answering the spirit of his question, but it's not correctly answering the question of which distribution TeX Live Utility will show as selected, or how you would change that distribution from the command line. (Speaking here as the maintainer of TeX Live Utility).

Comment: @AdamMaxwell: Do you want to post an answer? I would prefer that the GUI and command line tools use the same executables and packages.

Comment: @PeterGrill The shell script that TeX Live Utility uses to change the distribution is here: https://github.com/amaxwell/tlutility/blob/master/texdist/texdist_change_default.sh