# Running pdflatex from a RAM disk

Tags: texlive, mactex, scripts, bash, macos

For performance reasons. I would like to be able to run `pdflatex` directly from memory and not have to go to disk. Plan is to set up a RAM disk, `/RamDisk`, and run everything there.

Currently I have installed

```
/usr/local/texlive/2017
/usr/local/texlive/2018
```

and my source is of the form

```
$HOME/LaTeX/source
$HOME/LaTeX/texmf-local
```

Based on [Determine active distribution via shell script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/430934/4301), I can determine the current active distribution

```
DIST="$(kpsewhich -var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT)"
```

I will create the RAM disk and perform a

```
cp -rp /usr/local/texlive/${DIST} /RamDisk/texlive/.
```

which I will eventually modify to only copy over exactly what I need and not the entire distribution,.  I will also copy over my source directories as well:

```
cp -rp $HOME/LaTeX/source      /RamDisk/LaTeX/.
cp -rp $HOME/LaTeX/texmf-local /RamDisk/LaTeX/.
```

After compilation, I will copy over the pdf files from the RamDisk to my home directory so that they are not lost upon startup.

### Questions:

- What do I have to set in a bash script to ensure that the search path for executables such as pdflatex) etc is:

  ```
  /RamDisk/texlive/${DIST}
  /usr/local/texlive/${DIST}     (in case /RamDisk does not exist)
  ```

  and for packages is

  ```
  /RamDisk/LaTeX/texmf-local
  $HOME/LaTeX/texmf-local       (in case /RamDisk does not exist)
  ```
- Bonus: I only need `pdflatex`/`makeidx`/`xindy`. Is the subdirectories of `/usr/local/texlive/${DIST}` that I need to copy over easy to determine.

### References:

- [Determine active distribution via shell script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/430934/4301)
- [Create APFS RAM disk on macOS High Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46224103)

### Platform

- MacOS High Sierra (Version 10.13.4)

Comment: You must need *really* high performance.  Out of interest, what is your use-case?

Comment: To relocate the search path, change `TEXMFROOT` in your local `texmf.cnf` (read the instructions in `texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf`)

Comment: You should just need to set your PATH so the new copy of pdflatex is found, all the default search paths are relative to the executable location.

Comment: For performance an SSD in favor of a disk already makes a difference when compiling a large pdf.

Comment: If your runs are slow because you are loading a lot of files, preloading them into a format file would presumably be quicker than loading them from a ramdisk

Comment: @HenriMenke: Yeah. mine is not a usual case. I have thousands of individual documents that are compiled separately.  Theses documents extract content from other documents as well as numerous `.aux` _like_ files.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Oh, that sounds great. When I installed TeXLive2018, I edited `/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf.cnf` where I set `TEXMFHOME = $HOME/LaTeX/texmf-local` along with increases in `save_size`, `main_memory` and `pool_size` and ran `sudo texhash` and `sudo fmtutil-sys --all`. Do I need to alter the `/RamDisk/texlive/${DIST}/texmf.cnf` and rerun `sudo texhash` and `sudo fmtutil-sys --all`?

Comment: Yes, I did set up to use a format file a while ago but ran into a problem with a few of my files -- did not debug, but might also go back to that as well as running everything in RAM.

Comment: @ChristophS: Already have a SSD but RAM is still an order of magnitude faster than SSD. Also, doing everything in RAM and them copying all the files back will save a LOT of read/write cycles on the SSD.